How to Use the Send Activity or Send Event Trigger in Co-pilot Studio?
I'm diving into Co-pilot Studio and exploring its features, specifically interested in utilizing the Send Activity or Send Event trigger. Can someone provide a step-by-step guide or some insights on how to effectively use these triggers within Co-pilot Studio? Any tips, best practices, or examples would be greatly appreciated!
Ref
